# Check if any element of an array matches any element in MongoDB document array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

consider documents having array of colors

```
{
    Aid:"A101",
    colors:["blue","white"]
}
{
    Aid:"A102",
    colors:["red","yellow"]
}
```

I want to fetch the document which has any of the element matching the element from another array. Something like:

```
db.collectionName.find({colors:{$in:["red","cyan"]}})
```

but `$in` works only for single element, `$all` checks for all elements of an array however I want if any of the element matches, document should be returned.

Comment: So `$in:["red","cyan"]` matches the second document in your question. What are you expecting to happen differently to that?

Comment: Shit `$in` works, In MongoDB compass I was messed up in braces.